# Prevent updating fields with the same value in Prisma

Tags: postgresql, react-apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a datamodel type for example

```
type XYZ {
  id: ID!
  relatedTable: ABC
  someValue: String
}
```

Graphql part:

```
const createXYZ = gql`
  mutation createXYZ(
    relatedTableId: ID
    someValue: String
  ) {
    createXYZ(
      data: {
        relatedTableId: $relatedTableId
        someValue: $someValue
      }
    ) { ... }
`
const updateXYZ = gql`
  mutation updateXYZ(
    id: ID!
    relatedTableId: ID
    someValue: String
  ) {
    updateXYZ(
      data: {
        relatedTableId: $relatedTableId
        someValue: $someValue
      },
      where: { id: $id }
    ) { ... }
`
```

From the forntend I create XYZ record, with a mutation more or less like this:

```
  createXYZ(variables: {
    relatedTableId: 1,
    someValue: 'cde'
  })
```

server side:

```
  createXYZ: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
    return prisma.createXYZ({
      data: {
        relatedTable: { connect: { id: args.data.relatedTableId } },
        someValue: args.data.someValue
      }
    })
  }
```

Frontend side update looks similar to create

```
  updateXYZ(variables: {
    id: 2,
    relatedTableId: 1,
    someValue: 'cde'
  })
```

On the server side, in order to prevent from updating fields with the same value I need to fetch first XYZ record and compare before updating:

```
  updateXYZ: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
    const currentXYZ = await prisma.XYZ({ where: args.where })
    return prisma.updateXYZ({
      data: {
        relatedTable: currentXYZ.relatedTable.id !== args.data.relatedTableId
          ? { connect: { id: args.data.relatedTableId } }
          : undefined,
        someValue: currentXYZ.someValue !== args.data.someValue
          ? args.data.someValue
          : undefined
      },
      where: args.where
    })
  }
```

Does Prisma have any automatic way of detecting whether the received field value is the same as the current field value or is fetching and comparing values the only solution to this issue?

Comment: You really don't normally have to worry about this especially for single columns. Postgres always creates a new version (writes the complete record) when an update is applied. If it is actually an issue you can employ the function [suppress_redundant_updates_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html) in a trigger on the table.

Comment: What are you trying to do? As previously mentioned performance optimization is usually handled by the database (postgres) in this case.